# How can I sort a JSON list according to time (in milliseconds)?

Tags: python, json, sorting

I am new here and a beginner in Python. I retrieved a JSON list using requests which an example of the output is:

```
    {"data":[{"Id":"12345",
              "Name":"C123",
              "StartTime": 153507240000,
              "EndTime": 1535077800000},
             {"Id": "12346",
              "Name": "C124",
              "StartTime": 1530839700000,
              "EndTime": 1530864000000}
             ]}
```

And I would like to sort it according to the oldest (or lowest StartTime) to a new variable where I print out and format it properly but I have no idea how to do it

Comment: `sorted( d["data"], key=lambda x: x["StartTime"])`  ?

Comment: This is not a "JSON list" - "json" is not a data type, it's a text format, so what you have here is a python dict with a key "data" pointing to a python list of python dicts. How to sort a python list is extensively documented (in the official manual and all around the web).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sort` method with key `lambda e: e['StartTime']`

```
>>> d = {"data":[{"Id":"12345",
...               "Name":"C123",
...               "StartTime": 153507240000,
...               "EndTime": 1535077800000},
...              {"Id": "12346",
...               "Name": "C124",
...               "StartTime": 1530839700000,
...               "EndTime": 1530864000000}
...              ]}
>>>
>>> d['data'].sort(key=lambda e: e['StartTime'])
>>>
>>> pprint(d)
{'data': [{'EndTime': 1535077800000,
           'Id': '12345',
           'Name': 'C123',
           'StartTime': 153507240000},
          {'EndTime': 1530864000000,
           'Id': '12346',
           'Name': 'C124',
           'StartTime': 1530839700000}]}
```

To get the result in a new variable, use `sorted`

```
sorted(d['data'], key=lambda e: e['StartTime'])
```

Comment: I got how it works now, totally appreciate your reply, thank you.